# string comparison in Sandbox implementation

Tags: javascript

I run into this code in a reference Sandbox implementation (code is below). I think this implementation is well-known, as it is part of JQuery and also quoted in the book I am reading.

```
    var Sandbox = function(){
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);  
        var callback = args.pop();
        var modules = (args[0] && typeof args[0] === 'string') ? args : args[0];
        var i;
        ...
        if(!modules || modules === '*'){
            modules = [];
            for(i in Sandbox.modules){
                if(Sandbox.modules.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                    modules.push(i);
                };
            };
        };
..
```

The Sandbox() takes "*" as its first argument and a callback as its second. The question is about the first argument.

I.e. if I call

```
new Sandbox("*", function X() {});
```

the 'if' condition will fail

```
if(!modules || modules === '*') {
```

My investigation shows that the 'typeof modules' is 'object' after this line, when args[0] is any string.

```
var modules = (args[0] && typeof args[0] === 'string') ? args : args[0];
```

But the Sandbox implementation expects the if condition to be true.

So, what is wrong here...

Comment: What's your reference for this code? Which book are you reading? Is it possible that it's a misprint? That `args : args[0]` got switched?

Comment: The book Javascript Patterns (O'Reilly), Chapter 5. I also found almost identical code here http://jsfiddle.net/FiNGAHOLiC/885uA/33/

Comment: I can't figure out how "modules === '*'" can ever be true, no matter how you invoke the Sandbox() constructor.

Comment: AFAICT, `modules === '*'` will always be `false` because `modules` will be an array.

Comment: Thanks. I found the similar "unconfirmed errata" on the books webpage http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=9780596806767 so maybe this is NOT a reference implmentation used by Jquery after all.